# Why do I get a Type Error with my module because of a list in a class?

Tags: python

I created a module, with a class defined in. The class is "Somebody", so it's create a person with 5 settings.

Defining a person works good, but when I use a list in the class, I get an error.

This is my module gu_functions (with some functions removed) :

```py
class Somebody():
    brothers_sisters = []
    def __init__(self, genre, lastname, firstname, age, city, brother_sister=None):
        self._genre = genre
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname
        self._age = age
        self.city = city
        if brother_sister != None:
            self._brother_sister = brother_sister
            brothers_sisters.append((self,self._brother_sister))

    def __str__(self):
        return("Genre : {}\nLastname : {}\nFirstname : {}\nAge : {}\nCity : {}\n".format(self._genre,self.lastname,self.firstname,self._age,self.city))

    def family(cls):
        print(cls.brothers_sisters)
```

My main code :

```py
from gu_functions import *

jean = Somebody("Man", "ROVER","Jean", 14, "London")
print(jean)

sarah = Somebody("Woman", "ROVER","Sarah", 12, "London",jean)
print(sarah)

sarah.family()
```

Creating and printing jean is working. Actual result is expected result.
Creating sarah isn't working, due to the error, it should add a tuple with sarah object and jean object to the list "brothers_sisters".
Printing sarah is working.

EDIT : Traceback error :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mail\Documents\Développement\Python\My 1st module\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    sarah = Somebody("Woman", "ROVER","Sarah", 12, "London",jean)
  File "C:\Users\mail\Documents\Développement\Python\My 1st module\gu_functions.py", line 11, in __init__
    brothers_sisters.append((self,self._brother_sister))
NameError: name 'brothers_sisters' is not defined
```

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: sorry, I forgot it this time @ThierryLathuille

Comment: Class variables must be accessed though the insurance or class.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi How do you do that, because I can't use `cls` and `self`, isn't it ?

Comment: `Somebody.brothers_sisters.append((self,self._brother_sister))` or `self.brothers_sisters.append((self,self._brother_sister))` will be equivalent here, as you only mutate the list.

Comment: @Gugu72 You can use self, type(self) or Somebody.

Comment: Also, using `cls` instead of `self` in `family` doesn't magically turn it into a class method. There is a problem with your design, though. Making `brothers_sisters` an instance variable will only store the brothers and sisters of one user, without the concept of 'brother of my brother is my brother', and making it a class variable makes everybody part of the same 'family'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes:

1. add Somebody to Somebody.brothers_sisters.append((self,self._brother_sister))
2. declare family as class method

   ```
   class Somebody():
   brothers_sisters = []

   def __init__(self, genre, lastname, firstname, age, city, brother_sister=None):
       self._genre = genre
       self.lastname = lastname
       self.firstname = firstname
       self._age = age
       self.city = city
       if brother_sister != None:
           self._brother_sister = brother_sister
           Somebody.brothers_sisters.append((self,self._brother_sister))

   def __str__(self):
       return("Genre : {}\nLastname : {}\nFirstname : {}\nAge : {}\nCity : {}\n".format(self._genre,self.lastname,self.firstname,self._age,self.city))

   @classmethod
   def family(cls):
       print(cls.brothers_sisters)

   jean = Somebody("Man", "ROVER","Jean", 14, "London")
   print(jean)

   sarah = Somebody("Woman", "ROVER","Sarah", 12, "London",jean)
   print(sarah)

   sarah.family()
   ```

Output:

```
Genre : Man
Lastname : ROVER
Firstname : Jean
Age : 14
City : London
Genre : Woman
Lastname : ROVER
Firstname : Sarah
Age : 12
City : London
[(<__main__.Somebody object at 0x00000177AD9FC668>, <__main__.Somebody object at 0x00000177AD9FCC50>)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `brothers_sisters` directly inside your `__init__` function, using `self.brothers_sisters.append((self, self._brother_sister))` instead.